# Getting error on Vercel while trying to deploy Django

Tags: python, django, deployment, vercel

note: this is the edit of this post cause the issue I posted, i found a way to solve it and later encountered another one
i finaly found a way scale through that part of .build_files.sh problem , but now i am facing another issue on vercel,

Error: A Serverless Function has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 MB. : https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size

please anyone , who can help me here